# Update table joined to another table with different conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to update one table which is inner join to another table, but the rows which should be updated should have specific condition or not exist in the second table:

```
Update T1
Set STATUS = 'R'
From table1 T1
 inner join table2 T2
   on T1.ID = T2.ID and T2.STATUS = 'F' 

Update T1
Set STATUS = 'R'
From table1 T1
Where T1.ID not exists in(Select T2.ID from table2 T2)
```

How can I write it by one Query?

Answer (score 0):

You can do an OR in the where clause. Like the following :

```
Update T1 Set STATUS = 'R' From table1 T1 
    inner join table2 T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID and T2.STATUS = 'F' or T1.ID not exists in(Select T2.ID from table2 T2)
```

Comment: Sorry @Stephen but 'OR' can't work with one boolean condition in a side and a join in another one

Comment: Try this, I forgot to include the brackets. Update T1 Set STATUS = 'R' From table1 T1 
    inner join table2 T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID 
where (T2.STATUS = 'F') or (T1.ID not exists in(Select T2.ID from table2 T2))

Comment: With exists it has syntax error So i replace it with : Update T1 Set STATUS = 'R' From table1 T1 inner join table2 T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID where (T2.STATUS = 'F') or (T1.ID not in(Select T2.ID from table2 T2)) but it returned a wrong result as it check just the first part of 'Or condition'